# curl php weird behaviour

Tags: php, curl

I have a URL which if I open in my browser it works and I get the expected results.

When I try to get the content via php curl on my server, i get the  code 7 error ( could not connect to host )

The same script is working on my local machine

This is the code I'm using :

```
$url = "http://test.com";
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
$data = curl_exec($ch);
```

is it related to headers ? or is it related to php conf ?

Comment: Your browser uses a proxy.

Answer (score 0):

Your server could not be connect to the remote host.

Error no [7] = "CURLE_COULDNT_CONNECT"

Here is the detail error message:

https://php.net/manual/en/function.curl-errno.php